# Authentication uses # instead of `?`?

Tags: support, api, api-v2, authentication, oauth2

I need authentication for my app so I used the implicit flow way. The authentication works just fine but the `access_token` and `expires` variables return weirdly!

For example:

```
https://example.com/#access_token=cLTLp72w9VkU08MssPxkYNOg))&expires=86400
```

Shouldn't it be `?` instead of `#`? I can't access the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [the generic URI syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax), it is perfectly valid to have a *fragment* (The optional part of a URL that starts with an octothorpe `#`) without a preceding *query* (The optional part of a URL that starts with a question mark `?`).

This is how Stack Exchange returns tokens and other API's have used the same approach.  There is nothing wrong with it. In fact, **it is as [specified in RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2).**

The idea was that, by passing the data in the hash, this may make it harder for third-party servers or websites to access.  See also [OAuth2.0 Implicit Grant flow. Why use url hash fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733863/oauth2-0-implicit-grant-flow-why-use-url-hash-fragments).

---

Most languages, that you would write an app in, provide shortcuts to get at this fragment -- which usually called the URL *hash*.
For example, in JavaScript you would use `location.hash`.

Comment: thank you, turns out i need too use explict flow for authentication because my app is server side not client side.